# Boto3 S3 list_objects_v2 Not Returning Any Objects

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using Boto3 to try to get a list of keys from an S3 bucket via an AWS Lambda Python script. No matter what I try, the bucket returns no objects.

```py
    import json, boto3, os

def getConfig():
    cfg = {
        "aws_key_id": os.getenv("AWS_KEY_ID", ""),
        "aws_secret": os.getenv("AWS_SECRET", ""),
    }
    return cfg

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cfg = getConfig()
    bucket_name = "zachs-taxi"
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=cfg.get('aws_key_id'),
        aws_secret_access_key=cfg.get('aws_secret')
        )
    s3 = session.client('s3')
```

I've tried both of the following but both return empty:

```py
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=bucket_name)
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        print(content['Key'])
```

And

```py
    paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name):
        for content in page.get('Contents', ()):
            print(content['Key'])
```

The S3 bucket is public and I can access it. Inside there is a folder called content and within that folder is a .png file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual bucket? Can you share it if its public anyway?

Comment: **Side-note:** Just in case you're not aware, there is normally no need to pass credentials to an AWS Lambda function. Simply assign an IAM Role to the Lambda function and boto3 will automatically be given credentials to access AWS. It is not necessary to create a `session` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ran perfectly fine for me (with a different bucket name) when I ran it on my own computer:

```py
import boto3

bucket_name = "my-bucketname"

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
for content in response.get('Contents', []):
    print(content['Key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen for no apparent reason - the `list_objects` and `list_objects_v2` APIs both returned no `Contents` but did return `CommonPrefixes`, so they saw the objects in the bucket but didn't list them. When I switched to use `bucket.objects` from the [bucket resource methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html), then I got all the objects returned.